# Abstract with custom width

Tags: formatting, geometry, abstract

I am writing a report in which the page margins have been specified as `\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}`. But for one particular section (namely the Abstract), I want the left and right margins to be 5cm each. For that I used `\newgeometry{left=5cm,right=5cm}` at the begining of that section and `\restoregeometry` at its end. With this the new margins are obtained but the contents of this section are printed on a new blank page. [image]

I want to print this section on the same page as other sections. What do I do?

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
% ABSTRACT
\section*{\centering {Abstract}}
\newgeometry{left=5cm,right=5cm}
Neutron is considered as a fundamental subatomic particle. But it was not 
until 1932 that its existence was known. In 1932, James Chadwick observed
interactions between radiation and matter which could not be explained on
the basis of known particles or radiations. He proposed the neutron
hypothesis which could successfully explain all observations without
violating energy conservation. This paper discusses the discovery of
neutron by Chadwick and its acceptance of a fundamental sub-particle of
atom.
\restoregeometry
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I think it would be easier not to change the margins but instead to use `begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}`, if defined for your class (which you don't tell us). Or `\centering\begin{minipage}{<width>} ... \end{minipage}`. Or the `chngpage` package's `varwidth` environment. Or similar.

Comment: @cfr Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to change geometry, I would just accomodate a different-margined abstract.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Discovery if neutron by James Chadwick}
\author{Blah Blah}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\centering\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{abstract}
\bigskip
Neutron is considered as a fundamental subatomic particle. But it was not 
until 1932 that its existence was known. In 1932, James Chadwick observed
interactions between radiation and matter which could not be explained on
the basis of known particles or radiations. He proposed the neutron
hypothesis which could successfully explain all observations without
violating energy conservation. This paper discusses the discovery of
neutron by Chadwick and its acceptance of a fundamental sub-particle of
atom.
\end{document}
```

[image]

For classes in which the `abstract` environment is not defined, one might do it as show below (or else, in the below code, replace `\textbf{Abstract}\par\medskip` with `\section*{\centering Abstract}` as the OP provided in code)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Discovery if neutron by James Chadwick}
\author{Blah Blah}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begingroup
\centering\small
\textbf{Abstract}\par\medskip
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\par\endgroup
\bigskip\noindent
Neutron is considered as a fundamental subatomic particle. But it was not 
until 1932 that its existence was known. In 1932, James Chadwick observed
interactions between radiation and matter which could not be explained on
the basis of known particles or radiations. He proposed the neutron
hypothesis which could successfully explain all observations without
violating energy conservation. This paper discusses the discovery of
neutron by Chadwick and its acceptance of a fundamental sub-particle of
atom.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sensible approach! Though you might want to mention that `abstract` may not be defined, depending on the class. Or can you tell from the question?

Comment: @cfr, I could not tell for sure, but it sure looked defined from the picture.  I will provide an alternative, for when it is not.

Comment: The code has `\section*{\centering {Abstract}}` ...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the [changepage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{changepage}

\title{Discovery if neutron by James Chadwick}
\author{Blah Blah}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begingroup
\centering\small
\textbf{Abstract}\par\medskip

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{2cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}

\par\endgroup
\bigskip\noindent
Neutron is considered as a fundamental subatomic particle. But it was not 
until 1932 that its existence was known. In 1932, James Chadwick observed
interactions between radiation and matter which could not be explained on
the basis of known particles or radiations. He proposed the neutron
hypothesis which could successfully explain all observations without
violating energy conservation. This paper discusses the discovery of
neutron by Chadwick and its acceptance of a fundamental sub-particle of
atom.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here another soultion using a simple `list` as the standard `abstract` environment does. The solution is independent of the choice of the class and it should only be used in onecolumn settings (which considering your design guidelines is the use case anyways).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\providecommand\abstractname{Abstract}
\def\abstract{}
\def\endabstract{}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \centering\small
  \textbf\abstractname
  \list{}{\leftmargin2cm \rightmargin\leftmargin}
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist \par\bigskip
}

\title{Discovery if neutron by James Chadwick}
\author{Blah Blah}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  Neutron is considered as a fundamental subatomic particle.
  But it was not until 1932 that its existence was known.
  In 1932, James Chadwick observed interactions between radiation
  and matter which could not be explained on the basis of known particles or radiations.
  He proposed the neutron hypothesis which could successfully explain all observations
  without violating energy conservation. This paper discusses the discovery of
  neutron by Chadwick and its acceptance of a fundamental sub-particle of atom.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output_cut]